# How to save Qimage with 'jpeg' format in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I platform is `Windows7`, `Python3.4`, `PyQt5`.

I found that I can not save a `QImage` object in format `jpeg`.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
>>> i = QtGui.QImage()
>>> i.load(r"C:\Users\paleneutron\Pictures\Capture4.PNG")
True
>>> i.save(r"C:\Users\paleneutron\Pictures\hehe.jpg")
False
>>> i.save(r"C:\Users\paleneutron\Pictures\hehe.jpg",format = 'jpeg')
False
>>> i.save('hehe.png')
True
>>> i.save('hehe.bmp')
True
>>> i.save('hehe.jpg')
False
>>> i.save('hehe.jpeg')
False
```

In [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#save), `jpeg` is supported both read and write.

Why I got false when doing that?

### EDIT

I checked supported formats as comment:

```
>>> QtGui.QImageWriter.supportedImageFormats()
[PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'bmp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pgm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'png'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ppm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xpm')]
```

The problem is here, `jpeg` is missing!

But I have `qjpeg.dll` in `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\imageformats`.What should I do to enable `jpeg` in my program?

Comment: First of all check this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagewriter.html#supportedImageFormats Secondly, for jpg Qt requires special jpg  plugin(When you deploy app, it should be in imageformats directory)

Comment: Do you try to deploy exe? Or it is deploying of Linux app or it is just debug mode while you write code in your IDE?

Comment: @Chernobyl, it is ridiculous that I have to deploy exe to use a PyQt feature. But I got the solution by accident. I wrote the solution below.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python:) only c++ and Qt but knowledges in these fields sometimes allow me provide good answer for python+Qt. It's good that you found solution, so I upvoted answer and question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Chernobyl!

I got the solution by accident.

I tried the test code in my full program and it works well. It is because a lot of features of `PyQt` Must construct a `QGuiApplication` before using it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
print(QtGui.QImageWriter.supportedImageFormats())
```

Now we got the full supported formats:

```
[PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'bmp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ico'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'jpeg'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'jpg'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pgm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'png'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ppm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'tif'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'tiff'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'wbmp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xpm')]
```